# How to remotely clear remember_me cookie for another user in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies, remember-me

So I have this basic web-app with a protected back office area accessible by only one user (me). I wish to be able to remotely log off my sessions on other devices (another computer, my phone, etc).

In that way, I've implemented a `session` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `login_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_D044D5D4844A19ED` (`session_token`),
  KEY `IDX_D044D5D4A76ED395` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

along with proper handlers:

#### LoginListener

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Event\Listener;

// use ...

class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $em;

    function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
        );
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $currentSession = $event->getRequest()->getSession();


        $session = (new \AppBundle\Entity\Admin\Session)
            ->setUser($user)
            ->setSessionToken($currentSession->getId())
        ;

        $this->em->persist($session);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

#### LogoutListener

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Event\Listener;

// use ...

class LogoutListener implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface {

    private $tokenStorage;
    private $router;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, Router $router, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $this
            ->em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Admin\Session')
            ->findOneBySessionToken($request->getSession()->getId());

        $this->em->remove($session);
        $this->em->flush();

        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('blog_home'));
        $response->headers->clearCookie('remember_me');
        $response->headers->clearCookie('session');
        $response->send();

        $request->getSession()->invalidate();

        return $response;
    }
}
```

This works well when handling login and logout. The record is properly inserted on login and removed on log out. Now, I can do the following to remotely invalidate session:

```
public function clearSessionsAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = new Session();
    session_id('<whatever remote session id found in session table>');
    $session->invalidate();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blog_home'));
}
```

However, this won't work **if I checked 'Remember me' on login** for remote sessions.

Therefore, my question is: is it possible to clear 'remember_me' cookie for another user than the current one?

<sup>Of course, I tried to `$response->headers->clearCookie('remember_me');` but this ends *current* session.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can't really clear a cookie for another session because the browser for that session has to send a request before you can tell it to delete the cookie. This is an insecure way of logging people out anyway because anyone with access to the cookie can just re-add it manually and reuse the session.

The correct way of implementing this is to use the [`PdoSessionHandler`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html) to actually store your sessions in an SQL database and then if you want to log a user out remotely you can just delete the session in the database.

Comment: Will using `PdoSessionHandler` to remotely log off other sessions work even with `remember_me` cookie enabled?

Comment: @D4V1D Yes. And some more words because comments must be 15 characters.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try and come back to you with an acceptance of your answer if I'm successful :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried deleting records in the `sessions` table but when I refresh the page, I'm still logged in and the session record is recreated in the table.

Comment: the `RememberMeToken` has all the information to do the autologin, that's why invalidate the session isn't enough

Comment: you can use [`DoctrineTokenProvider`](https://github.com/symfony/doctrine-bridge/blob/688945134c2e456ac1d885256d632cdcf406f74c/Security/RememberMe/DoctrineTokenProvider.php) and remove that token... but I think there's some more elegant way to do this work

Comment: @Federico: Thanks for joining in. I did give a look to that class but I'm unaware of how to use it to achieve my goal. Care to post an answer?